# C#/XAML - Assets not shown when modified by code

Tags: c#, image, xaml, user-controls, uri

I created a user control, which is made with images.
I tried to modify them by C# method, for example:

```
imgElement.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms:appx/Resources/IconElement/my_icon_element.png"));
imgBackgroundElement.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms:appx/Resources/BackgroundElement/my_background_element.png"));
```

The soft finds images but doesn't show them ; the image control is empty.
If do not use the method and let images by default, they are shown...

Can anyone teach me why ? ^^

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try use absolute path?

Comment: How can i find the absolute path ?

Comment: Absolute path is path on your hard drive (e.g. c:\MyImages\my_icon_element.png)

Comment: Ok I tried and i got no error, but the problem still occurs, no images are shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An absolute path for your image will be:

```
ms-appx:///Resources/IconElement/my_icon_element.png
```